# jMeter adding threads/users (read from CSV Data) to a running thread group

Tags: multithreading, csv, jmeter

my problem is quite complex.

The matter is to test our web site answers to an increasing amount of requests from different users. 
So I can take users/passwords from a CSV Data and launch an HTTP request (with variables readen from the file). 
But I don't want to run the thread with **all** users at same time, but to loop and add at every iteration an other user from the file to the running thread groups (after some delay).

It seems very difficult to do so with jMeter. Perhaps I's need to call a custom java class ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just should use [Rump up](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/147922-max-users-is-lower-than-expected). This parameter control how fast your test will reach maximum threads count.
As explained in [JMeter documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html),

> The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the
>   full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up
>   period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10
>   threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds
>   after the previous thread was begun. If there are 30 threads and a
>   ramp-up period of 120 seconds, then each successive thread will be
>   delayed by 4 seconds.

Also may be this [Throughput Shaping Timer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) may be helpful for you. You can schedule duration of request with it.

Answer (score 0):

As Jay stated, you can use ramp up to try to control this, though I am not sure the result will be what you are after...though it will add the startup delay. If you have a single thread then each row of the CSV will be processed one at a time, in order.

You can set the thread group to 1 thread and loop forever. In the CSV config you can set a single pass and to terminate the thread on EOF.

CSV Data Set Config-->Recycle on EOF = False

CSV Data Set Config-->Stop thread on EOF = True

Thread Group-->Loop Count = Forever

Also keep in mind that by using BSF and Beanshell you can exact a great deal of control over JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out  [UltimateThreadGroup](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/)  from jmeter-plugins.